# EF join two tables into one model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

Using EF Db first, I have two tables:

`Table1: AppId, AppName, AppGuid [PK]`

`Table2: AppGuid [FK], Description, Url`

Can EF create a one entity from the both?

Meaning:

`App:
AppId, AppName, AppGuid, Description, Url`

**Update**

Thanks. I have made a view. Mapped it to EF. Now I get the following error: `Error  2   Error 111: Properties referred by the Principal Role App must be exactly identical to the key of the EntityType MaMDBModel.App referred to by the Principal Role in the relationship constraint for Relationship MaMDBModel.FK_AppsData_App. Make sure all the key properties are specified in the Principal Role.  D:\MaM\Dev\MamAdmin_1.0\MaMDBEntityFramework\MaMModel.edmx  768 11  MaMDBEntityFramework`

this is my edmx:

http://ge.tt/3rRWTOR/v/0?c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a ***VIEW*** using a ***JOIN*** between these 2 tables. After this you can use that View from EF.

Do this in SQL

```
CREATE VIEW [ViewName] AS
SELECT *
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.AppGuid = Table2.AppGuid
```

And import ***ViewName*** in your Entity Framework model (as you would do with a normal SQL Table) and use it to query whatever you need

EDIT: Have a look at this link for more info http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1990/how-to-use-sql-server-views-with-the-entity-framework/

Comment: is this the simplest approach ?

Comment: thanks. I know how to create view. Just wanted to verify this is the usual approach to such problem. I guess it is.

Comment: Thanks. I have made a view. Mapped it to EF. Now I get the following error: `Error 2 Error 111: Properties referred by the Principal Role App must be exactly identical to the key of the EntityType MaMDBModel.App referred to by the Principal Role in the relationship constraint for Relationship MaMDBModel.FK_AppsData_App. Make sure all the key properties are specified in the Principal Role. D:\MaM\Dev\MamAdmin_1.0\MaMDBEntityFramework\MaMModel.edmx 768 11 MaMDBEntityFramework`

Comment: Hmm .. weird. Haven't seen that error before. Try when creating your View to replace "SELECT *" with "SELECT Table1.AppId ...". I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem

Comment: have made this view. Named it `AppsData` and renamed its EntitySet to `AppsDatas`. However I get exception in code: `{System.InvalidOperationException: The EntitySet name 'MaMDBEntities.AppsDatas' could not be found.
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetEntitySet(String entitySetName, String entityContainerName)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.GetEntitySetFromName(String entitySetName)`

Comment: How can I perform save to this view via EF?

Comment: This link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236425/How-to-insert-data-using-SQL-Views-created-using-m talks about using a trigger, but there should be a way of doing it in EF